# How to push progress updates from PHP to page after user presses a button?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, server-sent-events

I have a series of buttons on a page that when a user clicks on them they trigger a **PHP** script via **jQuery** `.ajax()`.  Currently, I append a concatenated string dump of "progress updates" to a status placeholder DIV via the `success: function(data) { $('#divplaceholder').append(data); ...}` parameter. My problem is I would like to print real-time progress updates to that placeholder DIV as the execution "echoes" them.

I have read many SSE examples, tutorials, done extensive googling and I think I have an idea on how to send the "messages" back from the server but I have been unable to find an example on how to actually trigger *tasker.php* via jQuery to send the updates back **when the user actually pushes the button**.  Currently my `.ajax()` call is being triggered by a jQuery `.on('click')` event.

I'm getting lost and confused between learning to send the updates back via SSE and how to trigger the execution of *tasker.php* (and in some cases sending parameters to it, like `.ajax()` enables me to do).

Any help clearing this out would be appreciated.

**UPDATE #2:** [Found this example](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/03/pushing-updates-to-the-web-page-with-html5-server-sent-events/) but as soon as the JavaScript loads it is triggered; I want to trigger execution when the button is clicked.

**UPDATE #1:** TO ADD SAMPLE CODE
(Please excuse the formatting, I'm posting this from the mobile App)
This is an abstract it of how I have it implemented right now:

```
<? php
$output ="";
/*dummy code*/
read_csv_file();
$output.= "Opened and read file<br/>"; //Step 1
parse_csv_file();
$output.= "CSV file successfully parsed"; //Step 2
delete_from_directory();
$output.= "CSV file successfully deleted"; //Step 3
insert_data_into_db();
$output.=  "successfully inserted records into Database"; //Step 4

return $output;
?>


<div id="placeholder"></div>
<button id="button">Update</button>


//jQuery...

$('#button').on('click', function(){
.ajax({
url: 'tasker.php',
dataType: 'txt',
data:  dataVariable,
success: function (data){
$('#placeholder').append(data);
});
});

//jQuery...
```

Comment: What about wrapping your code inside the .on('click') with a setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);

Comment: It'd be useful to see some of your code. Do you mean you already have it working (i.e. but without progress updates) with `.ajax()`; what does that call look like?

Comment: @DarrenCook done. hope it helps. thanks!

Comment: wouldn't changing `$('#placeholder').append();` to `$('#placeholder').append(data);` solve this?

Comment: @imvain2 that's a typo; that's how it is right now in fact. just fixed it. but that dumps the whole string at once. what I want is to output each step as it is completed at runtime instead of having to wait til the "return".

Comment: I think you will need 4 ajax calls for every step. Also if you are uploading a file you can display progress with event.loaded and event.total

Comment: @Covik I think the solution is SSE but I really don't understand the concept well enough to implement it correctly :(

Comment: Thanks; if no-one else answers in the meatime, I'll try to post an answer tomorrow showing how SSE can be used. (**But**, is there much data in `dataVariable` ? SSE does not support POST, so it has to be short enough for GET, or you need to send the data first, then start SSE.)

Comment: @DarrenCook I'm currently passing one parameter. Thanks  for your help!

Comment: So i googled php server sent events and found this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

Comment: @DarrenCook hi! Any chance you might be able to post your thoughts about this question anytime soon? Looking forward to your opinion. Highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, finally posted an answer. (I've not checked this code, so let me know if it doesn't work: it is a bit late here, and I might have a typo.) :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, on the client-side:

```
var server = null;
$('#button').on('click', function(){
  if(server)server.close();
  server = new EventSource('tasker.php?x=123');
  server.addEventListener('message', function(e){
    process(e.data);
    if(e.data >= 100){server.close();server=null;} //6
    }, false);
  });
```

Points:

- You have to pass the parameter with GET
- I've assumed a `process()` that will take your progress updates, and alter the web browser display, somehow.
- If the button is pressed again, it closes any previous SSE connection, and starts a new one.
- 6: see `#6` on the back-end code below

On the back-end, PHP pseudo-code:

```
<?php
//Process inputs here
//If using sessions close them here
$lastProgress = 0;
while(true){
  $progress = ...  //1
  if($progress == $lastProgress)continue; //2
  echo "data:$progress\n\n";  //3, 4
  @ob_flush();flush();  //5
  //if($progress >= 100)exit;  //6
  }
```

Points:

- 1: Get the progress (e.g. look at log file, poll a DB, etc.)
- 2: Don't waste bandwidth; only send back new progress
- 3: I'm assuming `$progress` can only be a number. If any chance it can be text, you need error-checking, or json-escaping!!
- 4: `"data:"` prefix, `"\n\n"` is the SSE protocol.
- 5: The PHP idiom to be sure it gets sent immediately.
- 6: An SSE back-end is an infinite loop: the whole PHP process gets killed by Apache when the browser closes the socket. With a progress meter, you want it to die once we know there will be no more progress, but this has to come from the client (if the *server* disconnects, the browser will think the socket died and will try to reconnect). That is why this line is commented out. See `#6` in the client code.

As a final note, you could stick with Ajax, and listen to `readyState` 3 (also known as the comet technique). (That is how you make it work on browsers like IE11 and earlier; also the only way to be able to use POST.)(See my book, Data Push Apps With HTML5 SSE, for loads more on those topics.)

Comment: Great! I'll give it a try. About point 3, I was thinking about sending back text messages like "completed parsing", "inserting into DB", "finished executing", etc instead of a number for percentage. Also, not sure I understand what you mean about "If using sessions close them here". I have a login system and I do have session variables; not what happens if that's what you mean. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Update: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. Haven't had a chance to try to implement this yet. I'll keep you informed.